# difficulties importing relationship in Neo4j after creating nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship, bulk

I am using the Neo4j community edition. I have 13m nodes created in neo4j. Afterwards, creating the relationship from a CSV file. The process is too slow.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///re.CSV" AS csvLine 
WITH csvLine
LIMIT 3
MATCH(p:actor), (m:movie)
WHERE m.mid=toInteger(csvLine.mid)
    AND p.pid=toInteger(csvLine.pid)
CREATE(p)-[a:Acted{ptime:csvLine.ptime}]->(m)

Set 3 properties, created 3 relationships, completed after 128618 ms.
```

I would appreciate any help into this issue.

Comment: What is `r` and `p` variables that you are using in `WHERE r.mid=toInteger(csvLine.mid) AND p.pid=toInteger(csvLine.pid)`? Seems to me that your query is not complete...

Comment: Also, share with us your CSV file (or a sample lines of it).

Comment: Are you using index in the `mid` properties?

Comment: thx for reply. I indexed using
CREATE INDEX ON :movie(name,mid)  
CREATE INDEX ON  :actor(name,pid) 
sorry r is mistake it should be m!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes you referenced (`CREATE INDEX ON :movie(name,mid) CREATE INDEX ON :actor(name,pid)`) are for composite indexes, which requires that all of the indexed properties be present for lookup.

But in your query, you're only getting actor by pid (not pid AND name), and movie by mid (not mid AND name). If you want to index lookup by a single property, create an index on just that property.

Also, EXPLAIN your query to look at the query plan (PROFILE if you can, but only for queries that finish executing). That can often give you hints as to whether index lookups are being used, or if it's falling back to label scans.